# In 8086 assembly language, how do I shift sprite in video mode into another position without clearing it and drawing it again?

Tags: performance, assembly, optimization, x86-16, vga

In 8086 assembly language, how do I shift sprite in video mode into another position without clearing it and drawing it again.. i used the previous method but it is not efficient

Comment: What "previous method"?  You didn't link any other question or include any code.  Also, what system are you optimizing for?  emu8086?  DOSBox?  Real modern PC hardware in 16-bit mode?  (I assume not real hardware because even the most inefficient code is probably fine there, even if it has to round-trip over the PCIe bus to a non-integrated video card a couple times for every byte you touch.)  Or even a real retrocomputer like an 8088 or 286 PC?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [tour] and [ask].  For software-based sprites added directly to a bitmap, vs. the separate hardware sprites that were available on some 8-bit systems, you  really do need to repaint that part of the frame.  Or, often you build up the next frame off-screen then swap it for the visible frame.

Comment: One technique is a "shadow framebuffer" that you update in RAM, then memcpy it (or just the changed parts) to video RAM.  Helps even more if your CPU has cache, but avoids going over an I/O bus to get to real video RAM.  Or like @Dave S said, double-buffering gives you more CPU time to draw vs. trying to get it done during the vertical-blanking interrupt or something.

Comment: BTW, I tagged your question VGA based on usual assumptions for x86 PCs.  If you're using video hardware other than VGA, please edit your post.

Comment: Also, have a look on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x86+or+8086 for tricks that were used in real software for old hardware.  If *you're* optimizing for actual classic hardware, you could ask a question there if your searching doesn't find anything.  Optimizing for an emulator might or might not be off-topic, depending on the question.

Comment: VGA doesn't have sprites if I recall correctly.  It's a major limitation of the hardware.

Comment: @fuz - right, no hardware-based sprites like 8-bit Atari and C=64 had, it is a dumb frame buffer.  2D game objects are still often called "sprites" even when they are small bitmaps drawn on top of the background bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hardware supported sprites in the graphic mode of VGA.